# IF statement issues: MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, insert

I have a table called `contact`

I have a field in the table labelled `name` and a field labelled `email`.

I have a row with the value `Ryan` in the name field and a blank email field.

I want to run an if statement so it will insert the email `info@ryanmurphy.org.uk` into the `email field` if the `name` matches `Ryan`.

If it finds no matches then I want it to insert the row.

So far I have tried this:

```
 IF name = 'Ryan'
 THEN INSERT INTO contact (email) VALUES ('info@ryanmurphy.org.uk') 
 ELSE
 INSERT INTO contact (name, email) VALUES ('Ryan', 'info@ryanmurphy.org.uk')
 END IF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put the query in the question into a stored procedure

Answer (score 2):

I might be really wrong but wouldn't the following code work?

```
UPDATE contact SET email='info@ryanmurphy.org.uk' WHERE name='Ryan';
```

Comment: I need to check whether the contact exist first. Updated question.

Comment: You said : 
"I have a row with the value Ryan in the name field and a blank email field." 

So like @Cyrille said, update should work. Insert statement will insert a new row without name, is that what you want?

Comment: If you read the question now, i need to do an ifelse statement because if there isnt name=ryan then an else statement needs to be executed

Answer (score 1):

If name column is primary key, you could use replace command

```
REPLACE INTO contact (name, email) VALUES ('Ryan', 'info@ryanmurphy.org.uk')
```

In my opinion you should have keys or unique fields in your table. For example, if name is unique field you could use something like this

```
INSERT INTO contact (name, email) VALUES ('Ryan', 'info@ryanmurphy.org.uk') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email = "info@ryanmurphy.org.uk"
```

Are you able to change your table schema?

Comment: unfortunately name column is not primary key

Comment: So you want to UPDATE ryan's email if row withn name ryan is in table? If not, you just want to insert the whole row ?